# Shortcodes won't work on live environment

Tags: shortcode, localhost

I am currently developing a plugin that uses shortcodes. On my localhost everything works fine just using the shortcode, for example:

```
[bbit bandname="Lady Gaga"]
```

This shows a list of bandsintown.com gigs for the artist, like it's supposed to. Now when I install the plugin on a live website from the WordPress repo and I use the exact same code, the post on the website shows the shortcode, instead of the list of gigs.

More information:

- I already tried other plugins using shortcodes (like Contact Form 7) and they just work.
- The localhost WordPress and the live environment use the same theme (a custom child theme for "Responsive".
- Last version has been pushed to the repo, I checked.
- When I install the plugin on the localhost (from the repo) it works as well.

What can be the problem here?

[edit]
I downloaded the Debug Bar and the Debug Bar Shortcodes. It revealed that there's something wrong with registering the shortcode.

Answer (score 1):

So this turned out to be the problem:

After running using WP_DEBUG on the live site it turned out $this was not defined in the following line:

```
public function __construct(){
    add_action('init', function(){
        add_shortcode('bbit', array($this, 'shortcode_handler'));
    });
}
```

shortcode_handler is a non-static function here, and this code was all called in a static context. It seems there are some differences in my local XAMPP configuration and the servers configuration. I fixed it by removing the old code and adding the following code outside of the class:

```
add_action('init', function(){
    add_shortcode('bbit', array('BBIT_ShortCode', 'shortcode_handler'));
});
```

After that I just needed to make the shortcode_handler method static and there was a fix.

Comment: Try removing the quotes around $this. You're passing a string '$this' vs the value of $this.

Comment: O no that's just a typo in my answer, that wasn't in my original code.

Comment: With that out of the way, the real issue if you wanted to get this working as a part of a class is to avoid calling the add_action() the way you are.  Create a regular function in your class to add with add_action and you'd be able to have your short code handler inside your class.